# Drop all the columns of pandas DataFrame whose names match with the names given in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am dealing with pandas DataFrame (`df`) within a for loop that may have different columns. For example, for the first loop, df may have columns: "A", "B", "C", "D", and "E". For the second loop, df may have columns: "B", "C", "E", "F", "G", and "H". I want to drop certain columns *e.g.*, "A" , "F", and "G" from `df`. If I use the line below within the for loop, It will result an error: "['F' 'G'] not found in axis."

```
df = df.drop(['A', 'F', 'G'], axis=1)
```

Similarly, for the second loop, It will result an error: "['A'] not found in axis." How to solve this problem?

Comment: It's up to you but I'd unaccept my answer and accept BENY's... it's definitely the correct way to do it in pandas...

Comment: What is `"['F' 'G']`? That's not valid python (missing comma, quote, etc...). `drop` works when you've got the right column names. So you have different columns that you think. We can't say much about that because we don't have an example that demonstrates the problem. Perhaps just before the drop, print the columns and what you expect to drop.

Comment: @tdelaney "['F' 'G'] not found in axis." is a complete quoted error message that is produced when trying to drop labels which don't exist on a given axis (_e.g._ columns). That array notation (no commas between elements) is specifically how numpy arrays are formatted when printed and is valid within that context.

Comment: The problem remains: You don't have the columns you think you have. Maybe that's okay, maybe that's a critical error in your code that should not be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with pass `errors = 'ignore'`

```
out = df.drop(["A","F","G"], errors = 'ignore', axis = 1)
```

Comment: I'd completely forgotten about `errors='ignore'` - this really should be the accepted answer as it's far more elegant that using `df.columns.intersection`...

Comment: Can somebody explain how ignoring errors explains keys not found? Isn't the right answer to use the right keys?

Comment: `I want to drop certain columns e.g., "A" , "F", and "G"` - so the OP wants to drop those columns (**if they exist**)

Answer (score 2):

Filter the list of columns to only include those that are actually present in the DataFrame, eg:

```
df = df.drop(df.columns.intersection(['A', 'F', 'G']), axis=1)
```